# ViewPager do not behave elastically or get stuck in Views

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am working on `ViewPager` but a surprising problem comes up.

The `ViewPager` when scrolled to get next page, it **got stuck** **if I take my finger off from screen**, but normally the view should bounce back or next view should come up which it does not. Instead, `ViewPager` keep stuck in middle of both. I am loading bitmaps via `AsyncTask` and if I scroll fast there is no problem in loading bitmaps.

Here is preview of what I am trying to say -
[image]
(different color boxes are different screenshot combined in one image)

So if I leave picture while changing view, it just get stuck there, no bounce back or next view untill i manually scroll it. Here is `ViewPager` XML

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/albumArt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxHeight="220dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

And here is the code I am using: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html

Thanks for giving your time and ask me if any further code required.

Cheers

Comment: Has post gone dry? Any help appreciated, please

Comment: Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549969/android-viewpager-gets-stuck-in-between-views/31698424#31698424)

Comment: If you have n fragments set this option in for your viewPager: viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(n). It seems like your fragments are being recreated each time. This causes your viewCreated to be called, thus calling your parse(). I have updated my answer(mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(strings.size());